# Why can't find my Laravel session keys in Redis container?

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

I have setup my Laravel application with docker, one container is dedicated to the app one for redis.

I have setup Laravel to use Redis for session an caching.

All works fine but if I enter my Redis container and try to list all keys like:

```
 $redis-cli
 #KEYS *
```

It will return only key values used for caching not the session keys.

The above is a doublecheck because actually from Laravel application I set session key and then dump like

```
 <?php dump(session()->all()); dump(Session::getDefaultDriver()); ?>
```

and from the dump everything looks fine.
I see my session keys and values data structures. 
    Session::getDefaultDriver() //returns "redis"

So, by seeing Cache key:values inside redis container I assume that there's not a connection/docker container issues... Laravel is writing in the correct place. Redis default connection is shared by Cache and SEssion.

In database.php I have:

```
'redis' => [
'client' => 'predis',
'default' => [
    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'redis'),
    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
    'database' => 0,
],
],
```

In session.php I have

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'),
 ...
 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

By seeing the dumps returning correct values in Laravel web application I'm assuming session is working properly and points to redis.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add the `CLIENT LIST` output from redis? Also make sure your php app is connected and shows a connection in the same

Comment: looks like I see only one connection. The one I'm making on commandline from inside the container. Is the connection from laravel web app persistent and should be listed too?

Comment: On the redis cli, run the `info` command. At the end of the output should be a `# Keyspace` section. What does that say?

Comment: # Keyspace
db0:keys=2,expires=2,avg_ttl=16440517, I think it's referred to the two keys that I cache : KEYS *  returns : KEYS *
1) "wwws_cache:VNMmO5IGsngPBjiUU2yiy5OBAR1pzD3bmY0UY"
2) "www2s_cache:CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" - Still missing the session keys....

Answer (score 0):

run `INFO` command on your redis container cli ,at the end of the output is a #Keyspace part which lists your available namespaces on redis , you can switch to every one of them by runnig `SELECT` command . for example if your  keyspaces are :

- db0:keys=53,expires=43,avg_ttl=95982529
- db1:keys=5,expires=2,avg_ttl=15614644950
  you can switch to second one by running `SELECT 1`
  after switching to each keyspace  run `keys *` to see what is stored under that keyspace